# Center image over text in div

Tags: html, css

I have a container with some "*background*" text.
I want to center an image in this container and over the text.
**NOT** the text over the image.

The effect I'm looking to reproduce is as below where the shoe is over the **Desrupt**(?) text.

[image]

However, I am not able to center the image in the container.
I have created [**THIS PEN**](https://codepen.io/hansmoolman/pen/bzqxWw) to show what I have.

How do I create a similar effect as per the demo image?
Ideally, the image of the penguin should be 75% the width of its container and the "What is lorem" text should be able to be positioned in the container with e.g. margin-top at 20% (so that the text is more readable rather than be completely hidden behind the image) without affecting the position of the image.

My CSS

```
/* Image over text */
.image-over-text {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.image-over-text p {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 4em;
    margin-top: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.image-over-text img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 75%;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do this:

```
.image-over-text img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;                        /* horizontal alignment */
    top: 50%;                         /* vertical alignment */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* shift the image back to center */
    width: 75%;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

The `left` and `top` attributes move the image so that its top left corner is at the center of the container, then the `transform` shifts it back up by half of the image's height, and left by half of its width.

As for the text positioning, just give it `margin-top: 20%`, and you don't need a margin-bottom attribute.

Comment: I updated and saved the Pen with the suggested solution. The image is now centered as wanted, but relative to the text. If I reduce the margin-top of the text to e.g. 20%, the image moves with it and the penguins head disappears.

Comment: You need to give your `image-over-text` container some height, at the moment its only as high as its contents (not including the image, as that is absolutely positioned). Try adding `height:100%` to your `image-over-text` container.